# How to detect device is mobile when the website is clicked through TikTok?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Note: For some reason my code works for when the website link is clicked through Instagram but not through TikTok.

I am trying to detect that a device is mobile in order to render the screen differently. We have a 4 column grid layout on desktop and want to display only 1 or 2 columns if the device is mobile.

We declare const [columns, setColumns] = React.useState(4);

This is the existing code to detect screen sizes:

```
  window.addEventListener(
    "resize",
    function (event) {
      if (event.target.innerWidth > 700) {
        setColumns(4);
      } else if (
        event.target.innerWidth < 700 &&
        event.target.innerWidth > 600
      ) {
        setColumns(3);
      } else if (
        event.target.innerWidth < 600 &&
        event.target.innerWidth > 400
      ) {
        setColumns(2);
      } else {
        setColumns(1);
      }
    },
    true
  );
```

For the rendered component we pass in these props to GridDropZone from react-grid-dnd:

```
<GridDropZone
  disableDrag={true}
  id="items"
  boxesPerRow={columns}
  rowHeight={353}
  style={{ height: `${(items.length / 4) * 350}px` }}
>
```

It seems that this logic is good enough to only show 2 columns when I am on my iPhone via my Chrome browser. However, when I try clicking on the link to our website through a TikTok profile, it seems that we still display 4 columns. This does not seem to be a problem on Instagram. Why is this different than opening it Instagram and via my mobile Chrome browser and how would you recommend fixing this? Thanks!

Edit: This fix still only works on iOS chrome and not when I open the website through TikTok.

```
if (window.matchMedia("only screen and (max-width: 760px)").matches) {
        setColumns(1);
}
```

Edit: makeStyles()

```
const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  root: {
    backgroundColor: "#fcfcfc",
  },
  icon: {
    marginRight: theme.spacing(2),
  },
  heroContent: {
    backgroundColor: theme.palette.background.paper,
    padding: theme.spacing(8, 0, 6),
  },
  heroButtons: {
    marginTop: theme.spacing(4),
  },
  cardGrid: {
    paddingTop: theme.spacing(8),
    paddingBottom: theme.spacing(8),
    marginTop: 10,
  },
  card: {
    height: "100%",
    display: "flex",
    flexDirection: "column",
  },
  cardMedia: {
    paddingTop: "56.25%", // 16:9
  },
  cardContent: {
    flexGrow: 1,
  },
  footer: {
    backgroundColor: theme.palette.background.paper,
    padding: theme.spacing(6),
  },
  sectionDesktop: {
    display: "none",
    [theme.breakpoints.up("lg")]: {
      display: "flex",
    },
  },
  formControl: {
    margin: theme.spacing(1),
    minWidth: 150,
    maxHeight: 40,
    color: "black",
  },
  selectEmpty: {
    marginTop: theme.spacing(2),
  },
```

Comment: Why don't you use CSS media queries? You can use flex and change its properties easily in the query.

Comment: You don't even need media queries for this... flex grid is all that's necessary.

Comment: Do you get the same issue when you open the link through Tiktok on Android?

Comment: @PhantomSpooks I'm unsure if this is the case for Android since I'm on iOS and encountering this issue. I will probably ask a friend once I get this working for iOS first.

Comment: @Brad do you mind elaborating on this? Are you saying that flexboxes should naturally handle this?

Comment: @code Do you mind elaborating on this? I tried adding some media logic and it still only is detecting on iOS' chrome app but not when I open the website through tiktok. See the above post for the edit showing the fix I tried

Comment: CSS media queries are written with CSS and don't need JavaScript :) What CSS system are you using with React (modules, styled-components, styled-jsx, emotion, etc; don't tell me none, if you don't go use one)?

Comment: @IsaacFung See also:  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout  Basically, you'll use `minmax()` and `repeat()` with `display: grid` to set how things automatically grow/shrink and snap to new rows as necessary.

Comment: @code Not that sure what to call it, but we use makeStyles() with material UI to do all our CSS styling. I've added what that looks like to the above post.

Comment: MUI grid is responsive..., right? https://mui.com/components/grid/

Comment: @code Yeah exactly, that's why it's so confusing why it appears to work fine (only 1 or 2 columns) for iOS Chrome but not for when it's opened through TikTok; it still shows 4 columns.

Comment: How is it opened via tiktok? A link?

Comment: @code I figured it out! Yeah it was being opened as a link via TikTok in the original app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue resolved. As you can see I have a `window.addEventListener("resize", ...)` and it does work on making my grid 1 column for Instagram. However, this  did not work for TikTok because it appears that TikTok does not trigger the "resize" event when I click on my website through the app.

Thus, I created a separate resize() function and resize the window manually when the page is first rendered through useEffect(). I also added a new if statement that uses `window.matchMedia()` to check if the device is mobile. The code for the solution is shown below.

```
function resize(innerWidth) {
    if (window.matchMedia("only screen and (max-width: 760px)").matches) {
      setColumns(1);
    } else if (innerWidth > 700) {
      setColumns(4);
    } else if (
      innerWidth < 700 &&
      innerWidth > 600
    ) {
      setColumns(3);
    } else if (
      innerWidth < 600 &&
      innerWidth > 400
    ) {
      setColumns(2);
    } else {
      setColumns(1);
    }
  }
  window.addEventListener(
    "resize",
    function (event) {
      resize(event.target.innerWidth)
    },
    true
  );

  useEffect(() => { resize(window.innerWidth) }, [])
```